# OpenCV 2.0 with Visual Studio 2013 Professional

Tags: opencv, dll, 32bit-64bit

I have a project in VS2013 that's using 32bit OpenCV 2.0 libraries. It builds successfully, but when I try to run in Debug configuration, I get the following error message:
 [image]

When I run it in Release Configuration, I get this errror:
[image]

Not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: please, use 2.4.10, not 2.0.

Comment: the project has some code in it which was written using OpenCV 2.0. Will using OpenCV 2.4.1 require a lot of code change? and why specifically 2.4.1 ?

Comment: try to use a current version, not a 4 year old.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, OpenCV's API changed a little bit since 2.0.

**Nevertheless**, you will find that it's easier to install OpenCV 2.4.x and update your existing code than to **build OpenCV 2.0 from scratch with VS2013**, which is what you need to do in order to fix these errors.